# Remove top margin in SwiftUI app for Apple WatchOS

Tags: alignment, margin, space, watchos, vstack

My WatchOS app show a top margin and I don't know why. I'm using a VStack inside the main view, and I expect the title should be aligned top.
How can I remove the top space? The only think I found to remove the space is adding `.ignoresSafeArea()` to VStack, but I think this isn't a good solution.

My code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, world!")
            Image(systemName: "globe")
            Spacer()
        }
        .frame(height: .infinity, alignment: .top)
        //.ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}
```

Preview (with VStack highlighted):

[image]

Comment: Did you ever find a good solution for this?

Comment: No, I'm sorry :(